# Could not find build tools necessary . Facing error with devtools

Tags: r, windows, devtools

I am trying to install pacakage BTYDPlus (https://github.com/mplatzer/BTYDplus)

When I enter this command

```
devtools::install_github("mplatzer/BTYDplus", dependencies=TRUE)
```

It prompts me to install

```
Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools. Do you want to install the additional tools now ?
```

So, I went ahead and installed. I can see a folder RbuildTools in my C drive now. However

```
find r_tools() 
#returns TRUE
```

However when I try to install using Devtools , I get the same error again. I also tried assigning the path of build tools as per some suggestions but even that doesn't work

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="%PATH%;C:\\RBuildTools\\3.2\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin;C:\\RBuildTools\\3.2\\bin")
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem trying to install [gbm](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm) using devtools. I am using R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) -- "Very, Very Secure Dishes". Any luck finding an solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( . Moved to python lifetimes package

Comment: I updated R and R tools, and made sure R was pointing to the correct directory for the most up-to-date R tools, and it worked.