# Error when installing an R package from github: Could not find build tools necessary to build data.table

Tags: r, devtools

From within RStudio I'm trying to install the data.table package from github following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9656182/4945268), and the package seems to download without a problem:

```
> library(devtools)
> dev_mode(on=T)
Dev mode: ON
d> install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")
Downloading GitHub repo Rdatatable/data.table@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/Rdatatable/data.table/zipball/master
```

I then receive the following prompt:

> Building R package from source requires installation of additional
>   build tools.  Do you want to install the additional tools now?

Selecting "Yes" results in this error message:

```
Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build data.table
```

Thinking this might be an RStudio problem, I tried installing the package in the standard R console, but this also resulted in an error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo Rdatatable/data.table@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/Rdatatable/data.table/zipball/master
Installing data.table
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Robert/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOOKOKu/devtools246832c52ab/Rdatatable-data.table-4348ff4"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Robert/Documents/R-dev" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'data.table' ...
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c assign.c -o assign.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc: not found
make: *** [assign.o] Error 127
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="data.table.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="assign.o bmerge.o chmatch.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fcast.o fmelt.o forder.o frank.o fread.o fwrite.o gsumm.o ijoin.o init.o openmp-utils.o quickselect.o rbindlist.o reorder.o shift.o subset.o transpose.o uniqlist.o vecseq.o wrappers.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'
* removing 'C:/Users/Robert/Documents/R-dev/data.table'
Error: Command failed (1)
d>
```

I found three related posts on SO:

[Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096233/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build-dplyr)

[Error : Could not find build tools necessary to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914339/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build)

[Could not find build tools necessary . Facing error with devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002510/could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-facing-error-with-devtools)

The first two seem specific to Apple OS, and the third suggests an error specific to devtools, but I don't know if that's the source of the error I'm seeing.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm running R version 3.3.0 in Windows 10.

Comment: @Procrastinatus Thanks for that link.  When I execute the install.packages command described in those instructions, R reports "installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status".  In the interest of time, I'm going to skip this for now, and just use data.frame instead of data.table.

Comment: Why not use the [CRAN version](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) instead of the development version?

Comment: Because my code is affected by a bug that's fixed in the dev version.

Comment: It´s clear why your error occurs: You don´t have this package installed.
Try to install RTools (see link in the first comment)

Answer (score 28):

You can try:

```
options(buildtools.check = function(action) TRUE )
```

which is included in https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/212725628-Bug-report-with-devtools-install-github-in-RStudio-v0-99-1273-Preview-and-previously-with-Version-0-99-896

> ... should suppress RStudio's attempts to validate your build tools.

It works for me.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, it worked for me after too long searching!

Comment: this solution works in a conda environment in a remote machine. :)

Comment: Omg this is the answer! I tried so, so many things to get rid of this check to validate my build tools, and this did it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) when working under Windows. It's crucial that you download and select the correct version. Run

```
R.version
```

to get your version of R.

After installing, you'll probably need to restart R.

Comment: I went ahead and installed Rtools for my correct version, restarted R, then tried to install github again (trying for caret) and get the same error.

Comment: Note that Rtools is not a package, so install.packages("Rtools") won't work.

Comment: I get this popup though when running `brms::brm()` on Linux, so it must be a solution other than _Rtools_.